# Make a list of kickable members in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying to clean up my old server, and I want my bot to kick everyone below a role named "bot". (and keep everyone above it) So I think (correct me if I am wrong) would be to create a list of kickable members and then kick each one (forEach). However, I can't find a way to make this list. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is "that role".

Answer (score 1):

You can compare role positions with [`Role.comparePositionTo`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=comparePositionTo)

```js
// <guild> is a placeholder for the guild object
const role = <guild>.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === "bot") // get the role

<guild>.members.cache.each((member) => {
 const highest = member.roles.highest; // get the member's highest role
 
 // if the member's highest role is lower than the specified role, kick them
 if (role.comparePositionTo(highest) > 0)
  member.kick().catch(console.error);
});
```