# Check if bot has a higher role than the role (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a giverole command, so like !giverole {member} {role}, but how do I know if the bot highest role is higher than the mentioned role. I haven't tried anything yet because I am stuck, please help me.

I am using discord.js v12

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a list of kickable members in Discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64487095/make-a-list-of-kickable-members-in-discord-js)

Comment: @Lioness100 no not really, because my bot is in different servers and the name of the highest role can be different

Comment: You don't need to find it by name- you can just use [`client.user.roles.highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=highest) and [`message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=highest)

Comment: @Lioness100 ooo ok i will try it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your code looks like but an easy way to check if the role is higher than the bot is to see if the role is editable by the bot!
`if(!role.editable) return message.channel.send(":x: **I do not have the permission to use this command!**");`